# file-dir is not working to upload a file on azure blob from apache camel

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, azure-blob-storage

We have some folders structure created in an azure blob container and we want to upload some files from camel routes to this blob storage.

when we try to specify file-dir param its not updating it correctly , but if we specify the value in blob name then its uploading the file in correct folder .

can you please help me on why its not working if we mention the  folder in file-dir param

***Not Working :***

.to("azure-storage-blob://account1/container1?**blobName=file1.txt& fileDir=/folder1**&operation=uploadBlockBlob")

***Working :***

.to("azure-storage-blob://account1/container1?**blobName=folder1/file1.txt**&operation=uploadBlockBlob")

[image]

dependencies :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-azure-storage-blob-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: What version of Camel are you using?

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>3.5.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-azure-storage-blob-starter</artifactId>
   <version>3.5.0</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Try with 3.10.0 or 3.11.0 when its released soon

Comment: Thanks @ClausIbsen . i have tried with 3.10.0 . But getting the same issue . Will try with 3.11.0 when it's released .

Comment: Hi @ClausIbsen

I have just tried with 3.11.0 , but still i am getting the same issue .
Just wanted to check , if fileDir option is designed for this purpose (for producer ) as the description says its to store the downloaded file

Answer (score 0):

**Not Working because this path is belonging from consumer side.**

```
.to("azure-storage-blob://account1/container1?**blobName=file1.txt& fileDir=/folder1**&operation=uploadBlockBlob")
```

Example:

```
from("azure-storage-blob://camelazure/container1?blobName=hello.txt&accountName=yourAccountName&accessKey=yourAccessKey&fileDir=/var/to/awesome/dir").
to("mock:results");
```

Reference for above suggestion under consumer example : [Azure Storage Blob Service :: Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/azure-storage-blob-component.html#_consumer_examples)

**Soultion:**

You can also specify your path like this belonging from producer side.

```
.to("azure-storage-blob://camelazure/container1?blobName=blob&operation=uploadPageBlob&serviceClient=#client").to("mock:result");
```

**serviceClient (common)**

Autowired Client to a storage account. This client does not hold any state about a particular storage account but is instead a convenient way of sending off appropriate requests to the resource on the service. It may also be used to construct URLs to blobs and containers. This client contains operations on a service account. Operations on a container are available on BlobContainerClient through BlobServiceClient#getBlobContainerClient(String), and operations on a blob are available on BlobClient through BlobContainerClient#getBlobClient(String).

Reference from above suggestion is under Producer Operation example->`uploadBlockBlob`

[Azure Storage Blob Service :: Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/azure-storage-blob-component.html#_producer_operations_examples)